# My generic EnumSet method - can't access Enum.values()

Tags: java, generics, enumset

I'm trying to write a generic method for initializing an EnumSet value from an integer containing a bit mask.  I'm getting a compiler error I don't understand.  Here's my code:

```
   private <E extends Enum<E>> void setEnumSet( EnumSet<E> es, int iEnum ) {   
      es.clear(); 
      for (E e : E.values()) {   
         if (0 != (iEnum & (1<<e.ordinal()))) {
            es.add(e); 
         }
      }               
   }
```

Compiler error:

```
1>Javac...
1>.\wdqapi.java:266: error: cannot find symbol
1>      for (E e : E.values()) { 
1>                  ^
1>  symbol:   method values()
1>  location: class Enum<E>
1>  where E is a type-variable:
1>    E extends Enum<E> declared in method <E>_setEnumSet(EnumSet<E>,int)
```

Is there some special syntax for accessing the values() method of E?  (I'm a Java noob.)  Can someone help me past this compiler error?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do operations on generic types directly because at runtime type-erasure replaces all these with `Object`. Hence, the above code would be doing `Object.values()` which obviously doesn't work.

The way to do this is to use [Class.getEnumConstants()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29)

To do this you need an instance of `E` of the `Class` object of `E`. Again, remember that at runtime type-erasure will remove all references to the generic type.

Try something like:

```
private <E extends Enum<E>> void setEnumSet(E[] values,
      EnumSet<E> es, int iEnum )
```

or

```
private <E extends Enum<E>> void setEnumSet(Class<E> type, 
      EnumSet<E> es, int iEnum )
```

Comment: Thanks, John.  I went with passing-in the values array. Seems redundant but it gets the job done.  Again, tyvm -- especially for timeliness!  :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to passing in the values array, you can recover the `Class<E>` from the `EnumSet`.  If the set isn't empty, use `set.iterator().next().getDeclaringClass()`; if the set is empty, use `EnumSet.complementOf(set)` to get a non-empty set, then get an element and get its class as before.  (Strangely, EnumSet does not provide a method to get the enum class directly, despite having to store it for `complementOf` to work.)

Once you have the Class object, use [`Class.getEnumConstants`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29) as mentioned in John B's answer.